# ASUS UX305 Ambient light sensor

Tags: asus

On ASUS UX305 the ambient light sensor works with Windows 10, but it is not working on Ubuntu 16.10. Is there any way to get it working?

Comment: Read the output of `journalctl -b` and see if it is mentioned. Read the output of `lshw`, same.

Comment: You might find something useful in the related thread [How to make the ambient light sensor work on Asus Zenbook UX303](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635735/how-to-make-the-ambient-light-sensor-work-on-asus-zenbook-ux303)